# SQL command from C# through OracleCommand giving invalid character error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Following is the command i am trying to run in my C# code using oracle connection string and everything is fine(the same query runs smoothly in toad). However upon filling the dataset it gives an error of ORA-00911: invalid character. I can't figure out why, please help.

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
            "SELECT DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID, APPS.DAW_INV_ORG_NAME(DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID) ORGANIZATION_NAME,APPS.DAW_CAT_NAME(MC.SEGMENT4) PRODUCT,TRUNC(NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE)) TRANSACTION_DATE,"
            +"TO_CHAR(NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE),'MM-YYYY') MONTH,DSAT.ITEM_SEGMENTS ITEM_CODE, DSAT.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,"
            +"DSAT.CURRENT_FORECAST_QUANTITY PLAN_QTY FROM APPS.DAW_SCPDB_ASCP_TPP_V   DSAT,APPS.MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES   MIC,"
            +"APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES      MC"
        + " WHERE NVL(SCH_END_DATE,SCH_START_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(@vfrom,'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(@vto,'dd/mm/yyyy')"+
            " AND  MIC.CATEGORY_SET_ID=1100000061 AND  MC.CATEGORY_ID=MIC.CATEGORY_ID AND  DSAT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=MIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"
            +" AND  DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID=MIC.ORGANIZATION_ID"
            +" AND DSAT.FORECAST_SET IN (@vForecastSetDPL1,@vForecastSetDPL2,@vForecastSetURIL)"
            +" AND APPS.DAW_CAT_NAME(MC.SEGMENT4) ='MICRO WAVE OVEN';", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vfrom",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value= vfrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vto",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value= vto;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vForecastSetDPL1", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value=vForecastSetDPL1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vForecastSetDPL2",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value=vForecastSetDPL2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vForecastSetURIL",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value= vForecastSetURIL;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

All the variables used are of String type hence for date i must use TO_DATE.rest of the parameters are supposed to be string type.

Comment: Here's an Idea... why not convert that into a Stored procedure this way you don't have to worry about all they `Dynamic building of that mess`

Comment: First thing to do: use parameterized SQL instead of including the values directly in the SQL.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Just using parameterized SQL (and possibly a verbatim string literal) would make a *huge* difference here.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: that was my first attempt,however, after spending hours to resolve 'how to read ref cursor output in c#' i decided to give up stored procedure and use the query.

Comment: @DJKRAZE:I tried using string literals, gave me the same missing character error. i cant try parameterized SQL though

Comment: I totally Agree Jon I always use Parameterized queries how ever I was stating more for readability.. also If am not mistaken.. where is the `FROM` Clause..

Comment: here it is:
`+"DSAT.CURRENT_FORECAST_QUANTITY PLAN_QTY FROM APPS.DAW_SCPDB_ASCP_TPP_V   DSAT,APPS.MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES   MIC,"`

Comment: all the more reason to restructure that query and use parameters it's kind of hard to read all of that..

Comment: i updated the query with Paremeterized SQL, error persists.

Comment: Not only is this an sql injection target waiting to get owned, you are using functions instead of joins.  Please read about how to do joins in SQL -- then your queries won't be so slow.

Comment: @user1451836 - this was not tested with the new code -- `('@vForecastSetDPL1','@vForecastSetDPL2','@vForecastSetURIL')` should be `(@vForecastSetDPL1,@vForecastSetDPL2,@vForecastSetURIL)` if the query parametrization was correct.

Comment: @Hogan: it helped but the error of missing expression occurs..

Comment: all the recommended changes applied to the query, the error of missing expression persists..

Comment: Maybe `NVL(SCH_END_DATE,SCH_START_DATE)` should be `NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE)`?

Comment: no.. thats not the issue, its working without it on toad and its not working with it in my parameterized sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in your query you use "@" but for Oracle you need to use ":"

```
 BETWEEN TO_DATE(@vfrom,'dd/mm/yyyy') - incorrect 
 BETWEEN TO_DATE(:vfrom,'dd/mm/yyyy') - correct
```

To use Stored procedure you need to create output parameter returning sys_refcursor and everything should be OK

Comment: i do add refcursor out both in stored procedures and parameters but i am not able to store the data in a dataset..

Comment: If you use ODP.NET there should be no problems using ODP.NET objects retrieve cursors and fill dataset or datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending parameters we can build the query first and then execute it. In your code we don't need semicolon in `'MICRO WAVE OVEN';"`

```
    string _currentQuery = "SELECT DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID, APPS.DAW_INV_ORG_NAME(DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID) ORGANIZATION_NAME,APPS.DAW_CAT_NAME(MC.SEGMENT4) PRODUCT,TRUNC(NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE)) TRANSACTION_DATE,"
    +"TO_CHAR(NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE),'MM-YYYY') MONTH,DSAT.ITEM_SEGMENTS ITEM_CODE, DSAT.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,"
    +"DSAT.CURRENT_FORECAST_QUANTITY PLAN_QTY FROM APPS.DAW_SCPDB_ASCP_TPP_V DSAT,APPS.MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES MIC,"
    +"APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES MC"
+ " WHERE NVL(SCH_END_DATE,SCH_START_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('" + vfrom + "','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('" + vto + "','dd/mm/yyyy')" +
    " AND  MIC.CATEGORY_SET_ID=1100000061 AND  MC.CATEGORY_ID=MIC.CATEGORY_ID AND  DSAT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=MIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"
    +" AND  DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID=MIC.ORGANIZATION_ID"
    +" AND DSAT.FORECAST_SET IN ('" + vForecastSetDPL1 + "','" + vForecastSetDPL2 + "','" + vForecastSetURIL + "')"
    +" AND APPS.DAW_CAT_NAME(MC.SEGMENT4) ='MICRO WAVE OVEN'";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(_currentQuery,con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

### EDIT

Changes to your code. I have not tested with real data

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
            "SELECT DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID, APPS.DAW_INV_ORG_NAME(DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID) ORGANIZATION_NAME,APPS.DAW_CAT_NAME(MC.SEGMENT4) PRODUCT,TRUNC(NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE)) TRANSACTION_DATE,"
            +"TO_CHAR(NVL(DSAT.SCH_END_DATE,DSAT.SCH_START_DATE),'MM-YYYY') MONTH,DSAT.ITEM_SEGMENTS ITEM_CODE, DSAT.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,"
            +"DSAT.CURRENT_FORECAST_QUANTITY PLAN_QTY FROM APPS.DAW_SCPDB_ASCP_TPP_V   DSAT,APPS.MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES   MIC,"
            +"APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES      MC"
        + " WHERE NVL(SCH_END_DATE,SCH_START_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:vfrom,'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(:vto,'dd/mm/yyyy')"+
            " AND  MIC.CATEGORY_SET_ID=1100000061 AND  MC.CATEGORY_ID=MIC.CATEGORY_ID AND  DSAT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=MIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID"
            +" AND  DSAT.ORGANIZATION_ID=MIC.ORGANIZATION_ID"
            +" AND DSAT.FORECAST_SET IN (:vForecastSetDPL1,:vForecastSetDPL2,:vForecastSetURIL)"
            +" AND APPS.DAW_CAT_NAME(MC.SEGMENT4) ='MICRO WAVE OVEN'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("vfrom",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value= vfrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("vto",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value= vto;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("vForecastSetDPL1", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value=vForecastSetDPL1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("vForecastSetDPL2",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value=vForecastSetDPL2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("vForecastSetURIL",OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value= vForecastSetURIL;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

post errors if these solutions doesnt work for you